# Saving and Retrieving Array and Displaying in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am creating a log where I am trying to store a couple of strings that are created by the user, and later retrieved and displayed in my list view (lwItems). However, my current issue is that whenever the user writes a string, the entire table is overwritten. How can I change my code so that an array is saved to shared preferences and the string is appended to it without destroying previous entries? Here is my java class- ("customValues" is being passed to it by my class where the user is entering their string)

```
public class Training1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView lwItems;
    private Button btnChangeItems;    
    private String DEFAULT_ITEMS_VALUES_STRING = "Item 1; Item 2";
    private String customItemString;
    private static SharedPreferences preferenceItems;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        lwItems = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lwItems);
        preferenceItems = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("items", 0);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
            Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.traning_menu_itemdetail, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add:
                Intent trainingCreateIntent = new Intent(getContext(), Training2.class);
                startActivity(trainingCreateIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle setItemsIntent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (setItemsIntent != null) {
            customItemString = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("customValues");
        }

        String[] items;
        String preferenceItemsString = preferenceItems.getString("customValues", null);
        if (preferenceItemsString != null) {
            items = getSplitAndTrim(preferenceItemsString);
        } else {
            items = getSplitAndTrim(DEFAULT_ITEMS_VALUES_STRING);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
        lwItems.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        lwItems.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (customItemString != null) {
            putStringInPreferences("customValues", customItemString);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Training2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String textOfItem = String.valueOf(((TextView) view).getText());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textOfItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static void putStringInPreferences(String key, String customItemString) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferenceItems.edit();
        editor.putString(key, customItemString);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @NonNull
    private String[] getSplitAndTrim(String preferenceItemsString) {
        return preferenceItemsString.trim().split("\\s*;\\s*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that in this method:

```
public static void putStringInPreferences(String key, String customItemString) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferenceItems.edit();
    editor.putString(key, customItemString);
    editor.commit();
}
```

You'll want to first read out the original value first, append the new item, and write out the new string instead.  This code is simply overwriting the old string with the new string on every call.